# Extracting coordinates of pixels inside polygon in Google Earth Engine as single feature

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-fusion-tables

IMPORTS:

```
var geometry = /* color: #d63000 */ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-67.76435852050781, -22.213792811479802],
      [-67.76641845703125, -22.220785143658368],
      [-67.75646209716797, -22.228412744835992],
      [-67.74410247802734, -22.230319580297703],
      [-67.7420425415039, -22.221420792936158],
      [-67.74341583251953, -22.212203596469955],
      [-67.74787902832031, -22.207753698686023],
      [-67.75543212890625, -22.213474969917876]]]);
```

CODE I have tried :

```
var fg_points = ee.Feature(geometry);
```

I thought if we give geometry as a feature it will select all points in that polygon but it isn't.

I have used randomPoints command but it is not evenly selecting all the points what I want is at least a point from each pixel.
and the randomPoints command is selecting the same points again and again.

Comment: Yes, I am only getting vertices from that how to get points inside that polygon...Please help me with this.

Comment: what do you mean by *points inside that polygon*? do you mean like a grid of points?

Comment: Yes like a MultiPoint Geometry that covers each and every pixel of a LANDSAT Image.

Comment: You should change the title to *Extract coordinates of pixels inside a polygon in GEE*

Comment: Sorry about that. Now, it's fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
var bounds = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-67.76435852050781, -22.213792811479802],
      [-67.76641845703125, -22.220785143658368],
      [-67.75646209716797, -22.228412744835992],
      [-67.74410247802734, -22.230319580297703],
      [-67.7420425415039, -22.221420792936158],
      [-67.74341583251953, -22.212203596469955],
      [-67.74787902832031, -22.207753698686023],
      [-67.75543212890625, -22.213474969917876]]]);

var l8 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR")
           .filterBounds(bounds);

// TEST IMAGE
var first = ee.Image(l8.first()).clip(bounds)

// get image projection
var proj = first.select([0]).projection()

// get coordinates image
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj)
Map.addLayer(first, {bands:['B1'], min:0, max:500}, 'Image')

// put each lon lat in a list
var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: bounds,
  scale: 30
})

// get lat & lon
var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'))
var lon = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'))

// zip them. Example: zip([1, 3],[2, 4]) --> [[1, 2], [3,4]]
var point_list = lon.zip(lat)

// Create points
var mp = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(point_list)
Map.addLayer(mp,{}, 'Points')
```