# Getting surrounding pixel coordinates from ee.Geometry.Point

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Not the best example, but say I have an image of Sea Surface Temperature and a point like so:

```
 // Load an image of sea surface temperature (SST).
var sst = ee.Image('NOAA/AVHRR_Pathfinder_V52_L3/20120802025048')
  .select('sea_surface_temperature')
  .rename('sst')
  .divide(100);

var geometry = ee.Geometry.Point([-81.2338, 42.4274])
```

Assuming variable "geometry" to be the center point, I would like to get the pixel coordinates 1 pixel west, northwest, north, northeast, etc. From there, I would try to get the pixel values, but I think I can figure out the rest. Essentially, I am trying to create a 3 pixel by 3 pixel window of sorts using a single center point as the input to construct said window.

Answer (score 2):

This code, adapted from [Extracting coordinates of pixels inside polygon in Google Earth Engine as single feature](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/293109), might be what you are looking for.

```
//get projection and scale
var proj = sst.projection();
var scale = proj.nominalScale()

// get coordinates image
var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj);

//Create a geometry object at the true center of the pixel
var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: geometry,
  scale: 30
});
var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'));
var lon = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'));
var point_list = lon.zip(lat);
var center = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(point_list);

// Create your window by buffering by the scale
var mywindow = center.buffer(scale);
```

Repeat the above process but using the window geometry this time

```
var coords = latlon.select(['longitude', 'latitude'])
                 .reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
  geometry: mywindow,
  scale: 30
});
var lat = ee.List(coords.get('latitude'));
var lon = ee.List(coords.get('longitude'));
var point_list = lon.zip(lat);
var centerpoints = ee.Geometry.MultiPoint(point_list);
```

Now extract values from the original raster?

```
var values = sst.reduceRegion({
reducer: ee.Reducer.toList(),
geometry: centerpoints,
scale: 30
});
```

I am not sure why the scale needs to be specified at 30, but it seems to work.

Comment: Thanks so much! Do you know what the ee.Reducer.toList() is doing in the reduceRegion()? I don't understand what it does in this case given there are no inputs that go into ee.Reducer.toList().

Comment: It's creating a reducer object to be passed to the .ReduceRegion() method ... basically telling it HOW to do the reduction.

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_intro

Comment: So essentially, ee.Reducer.toList() is simply aggregating all the data without doing any sort of arithmetic computations? I just tried out the code in Earth Engine and this is very close to what I need. Rather than creating a buffer, my windows needs to be more of a square. From the center pixel that "var coords" computes, I need to figure out how to get the pixel coordinates from one pixel above that center pixel, one pixel northwest, one pixel west etc. until I get a 3 pixel by 3 pixel window. Thanks again for the input. Definitely helpful.

Comment: Oh wait a sec. So "var coords" computes the center of the pixel, but I need the entire pixel. I'm guessing this would be a polygon with 4 vertices. I can probably still use the center geometry object that "coords"creates to figure out how to create a polygon representing the entire pixel somehow. Is buffering by the scale creating the full pixel? The buffer would be double the area of a regular pixel, wouldn't it? And the buffer creates a circular polygon, which wouldn't match the shape of a square.  Sorry for all the comments. I am thinking aloud at the same time I am writing stuff.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding your ultimate goal. Why do you need a polygon representing each pixel? My understanding was that you were simply trying to get the pixel values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99590/discussion-between-nick-and-adriano-matos).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: in JS you can make a buffer around the point, and build a rectangle polygon based on buffer:

```
var point = ee.Geometry.Point(-122.082, 37.42);
```

Apply the buffer method to the Point object.

```
var pointBuffer = point.buffer({'distance': 100});// unit is meters
```

make a polygon based on bounds:

```
var polygonBounds = pointBuffer.bounds();//this gives you the polygon you needed
```

If you code in  python, a manual way is to:

Cut an aoi around each lat/long point. Change 0.0001 to size that works for your AOI(consider the pixel size of the image.):

```
size = 0.0001 // this is equivalent of almost 10 m, ending in AOI of 30 m.
```

making 4 corner points of AOI:

```
cords = [[long-1.5*size, lat+size], [long-1.5*size, lat-size], 
      [long+1.5*size, lat-size], [long+1.5*size, lat+size]]
```

making AOI:

```
aoi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(cords, None, False) #order is longitude then latitude.
```

get the image collection and export it by geemap:

```
images = ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR") \
.filterBounds(aoi) \
.filterDate('2021-11-05', '2021-11-10') \
.filter('CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE < 25')

geemap.ee_export_image_collection(images, scale=10, 
                                out_dir= '/content', region=aoi, file_per_band=True)
```